# MySql Table Identifiers in insert statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There are tables database_product and database_orders in the database, which are being selected using `p.rid` and `o.userid`. How do the `p` and `o` get defined to point to database_product and database_orders?

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT p.rid, o.userid
        FROM {$this->dbtable}_orders o
        INNER JOIN {$this->dbtable}_product p ON p.productid = o.productid AND p.status = 'active'
        WHERE o.oid = %d AND o.transaction_id = %s
        LIMIT 1
        ",
        $oid, $tid
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implicit "as" keyword in the query definition. 
Read the query as follows:

```
SELECT p.rid, o.userid
FROM {$this->dbtable}_orders as o
INNER JOIN {$this->dbtable}_product as p ON p.productid = o.productid AND p.status =   'active'
WHERE o.oid = %d AND o.transaction_id = %s
LIMIT 1
```

You can use the "as" keyword to alias tables helping you write shorter, more clear 
queries

Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html for details

Comment: I recommend always using the key word 'as' so that the query is more readable and it is explicit that an alias has been assigned. It also helps to avoid other syntax errors if you are prone to dropping commas or other typos.

Answer (score 0):

In your select, the statement

```
{$this->dbtable}_orders o
```

forexample, says that the {$this->dbtable}_orders has "o" as alias. So you can refer the table as "o" in other expressions.